# Case expression on a created column

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have set up a view in Microsoft SQL Server. The portion of the view which I am showing creates a column named Starch. How can I manipulate that created column within a case expression to decide if it is above or below 2?

```
.
..
...
MAX(CASE WHEN R.ANALYTE = 'Starch'  then 
(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(R.RN5) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float,R.RN5) ELSE convert(float,0) END)  end) as [Starch],

CASE 
WHEN Starch > 2 THEN 'ABOVE'
ELSE 'Below' END 
As 'Starch_Cautionary',
...
..
.
```

Comment: Careful using `ISNUMERIC()` for conversion validation. What version of SQL Server? Also, sample data and expected output would help this.

Comment: You want to use created column Starch in the same query? or what?

Comment: This unrelated to question, but addition to @scsimon comment SQL Server 2012 and above, you can check [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) function to replace that whole IF THEN ELSE part

Comment: Yup @NenadZivkovic and just why I asked! Good link for OP

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `ISNUMERIC` still doesn't cause a conversion error (which it could depending on the data, even when it = 1) then you could wrap this in a `CTE` among other things.

```
with cte as(
.
..
...
MAX(CASE WHEN R.ANALYTE = 'Starch'  then 
(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(R.RN5) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float,R.RN5) ELSE convert(float,0) END)  end) as [Starch],
...
..
.)

select
   *,
   CASE 
   WHEN Starch > 2 THEN 'ABOVE'
   ELSE 'Below' END 
   As 'Starch_Cautionary',
...
..
.
from  cte
```

**Example of ISNUMERIC() Failing... Sort of... Atleast for your case**

```
declare @table table (i varchar(16))
insert into @table
values
('$'),
('1e4'),
('1,256,233'),
('5D105')

select isnumeric(i) from @table
```

These all return true, but would fail the convert...